# Python - Installing Pycrypto package

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, pycrypto

I am using Pycharm and i need to install a package called **pycrypto**. But when i tried it is giving an error like

*Collecting pycrypto*

Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pycrypto/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pycrypto/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pycrypto/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pycrypto/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pycrypto/

**Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycrypto (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pycrypto**

FYI

I tried this on both pycharm and python command line but both giving this same error. i am using python 2.7. Help me with the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you attempting to use pip to install pycrypto?

Comment: yes i used pip in command line and also tried in pycharm @ocelot

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall openssl by

```
brew uninstall openssl
brew install openssl
```

As suggested by Homebrew, do the following:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Comment: @Vignesh Karthikeyan did this answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the exception, you can see that the connection to pypi.python.org fails.

According to status.python.org, PyPI is up and running and my own tests confirm that. There seems to be a problem with your network connection.

If you can access the URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycrypto/ in the browser, check if you have to configure pip to use a proxy.